# application memory optimization

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, rss

We have a project written in ANSI C. Generally the memory consumption was not a big concern, but now we have a request to fit our program into 256 KB of RAM. I don't have  this exact platform on hands, so I compile  my project under 32 bit x86 Linux (because it provides enough different tools to evaluate the memory consumption), optimize what I can, remove some features and eventually I have  to have the conclusion: what features we need to sacrifice to be able to run on very small systems (if we're able at all). First of all I did a research what exactly a memory size in linux and it seems I have to optimize the RSS size, not VSZ. But in linux even a smallest program which prints "Hello world!" once a second consumes 285-320 KB in RSS:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <unistd.h>
#include  <signal.h>

unsigned char  cuStopCycle = 0;

void SigIntHandler(int signo)
{
   printf("SIGINT received, terminating the program\n");
   cuStopCycle = 1;
}

int main()
{  
   signal( SIGINT, SigIntHandler);

   while(!cuStopCycle)
   {
      printf("Hello, World!\n");
      sleep(1);
   }
   printf("Exiting...\n");
}

user@Ubuntu12-vm:~/tmp/prog_size$ size ./prog_size     
text       data     bss     dec     hex filename    
1456        272      12    1740     6cc ./prog_size

root@Ubuntu12-vm:/home/app# ps -C prog_size -o pid,rss,vsz,args   
PID     RSS    VSZ   COMMAND 
22348   316   2120   ./prog_size
```

Obviously this program will perfectly run on small PLCs, with 64KB of RAM. It is just linux loads a lot of libs. I generate a map file for this program and all this data + bss comes from the CRT library. I need to mention that if I add some code to this project - 10,000 times "a = a + b" or manipulate arrays 2000 long  int variables, I see the difference in code size, bss size but eventually the RSS size of the process is the same, it doesn't affected)

So I take this as a baseline, the point I want to reach (and which I will never reach, because I need more functions than just print a message once a second).

So here comes my project, where I removed all extra features, removed all auxiliary functions, removed everything except the basic functionality. There are some ways to optimize more, but not that much, what could be removed is already taken away:

```
root@Ubuntu12-vm:/home/app/workspace/proj_sizeopt/Cmds# ls -l App 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42520 Jul 13 18:33 App

root@Ubuntu12-vm:/home/app/workspace/proj_sizeopt/Cmds# size ./App 
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  37027     404     736   38167    9517 ./App
```

So I have **~36KB** of code and **~1KB** of data. I do not call malloc inside of my project, I use a shared memory allocation with a wrapper library so I can control how much memory is allocated:

```
The total memory size allocated is 2052 bytes
```

Under the hood there are malloc calls obviously, if I substitute 'malloc' calls with  my function which summarize all alloc requests I see that **~2.3KB** of memory is allocated:

```
 root@Ubuntu12-vm:/home/app/workspace/proj_sizeopt/Cmds# LD_PRELOAD=./override_malloc.so ./App
Malloc allocates 2464 bytes total
```

Now I run my project amd see that it **consumes 600KB of RAM**.

```
root@Ubuntu12-vm:/home/app/workspace/proj_sizeopt# ps -C App -o pid,rss,vsz,args
  PID   RSS    VSZ COMMAND
22093   604   2340 ./App
```

**I do not understand why it eats so much memory. The code size is small. There is not much memory allocated. The size of data is small. Why it takes so much memory?** I tried to analyze the mapping of the process:

```
root@Ubuntu12-vm:/home/app/workspace/proj_sizeopt# pmap -x 22093
22093:   ./App
Address   Kbytes     RSS   Dirty Mode   Mapping
08048000       0      28       0 r-x--  App
08052000       0       4       4 r----  App
08053000       0       4       4 rw---  App
09e6a000       0       4       4 rw---    [ anon ]
b7553000       0       4       4 rw---    [ anon ]
b7554000       0      48       0 r-x--  libpthread-2.15.so
b756b000       0       4       4 r----  libpthread-2.15.so
b756c000       0       4       4 rw---  libpthread-2.15.so
b756d000       0       8       8 rw---    [ anon ]
b7570000       0     300       0 r-x--  libc-2.15.so
b7714000       0       8       8 r----  libc-2.15.so
b7716000       0       4       4 rw---  libc-2.15.so
b7717000       0      12      12 rw---    [ anon ]
b771a000       0      16       0 r-x--  librt-2.15.so
b7721000       0       4       4 r----  librt-2.15.so
b7722000       0       4       4 rw---  librt-2.15.so
b7731000       0       4       4 rw-s-    [ shmid=0x70000c ]
b7732000       0       4       4 rw-s-    [ shmid=0x6f800b ]
b7733000       0       4       4 rw-s-    [ shmid=0x6f000a ]
b7734000       0       4       4 rw-s-    [ shmid=0x6e8009 ]
b7735000       0      12      12 rw---    [ anon ]
b7738000       0       4       0 r-x--    [ anon ]
b7739000       0     104       0 r-x--  ld-2.15.so
b7759000       0       4       4 r----  ld-2.15.so
b775a000       0       4       4 rw---  ld-2.15.so
bfb41000       0      12      12 rw---    [ stack ]
-------- ------- ------- ------- -------
total kB    2336       -       -       -
```

And it looks like the program size (in RSS) is **only 28KB**, the rest is consumed by shared libraries. BTW I do not use posix threads, I do not explicitly link to it, but somehow the linker anyway links this library I have no idea why (this is not really important). If we look at the mapping in more details:

```
root@Ubuntu12-vm:/home/app/workspace/proj_sizeopt# cat /proc/22093/smaps 
08048000-08052000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 344838     /home/app/workspace/proj_sizeopt/Cmds/App
Size:                 40 kB
Rss:                  28 kB
Pss:                  28 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:        28 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:           28 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB

...

09e6a000-09e8b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
Size:                132 kB
Rss:                   4 kB
Pss:                   4 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         4 kB
Referenced:            4 kB
Anonymous:             4 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB

...

b7570000-b7714000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 34450      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
Size:               1680 kB
Rss:                 300 kB
Pss:                   7 kB
Shared_Clean:        300 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:          300 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB

...

b7739000-b7759000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 33401      /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
Size:                128 kB
Rss:                 104 kB
Pss:                   3 kB
Shared_Clean:        104 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:          104 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB

...

bfb41000-bfb62000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Size:                136 kB
Rss:                  12 kB
Pss:                  12 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:        12 kB
Referenced:           12 kB
Anonymous:            12 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
```

1. So I see that RSS size for my project is **40KB**, but only **28 KB** is used. Does it mean that this project will fit into **256 KB of RAM**?
2. The **heap** size is **132KB** but only **4 KB** is used. Why is that? I'm sure it will be different on the small embedded platform.
3. The **stack** is **136KB** but only **12KB** is used.
4. GLIBC/LD obviously consume some memory, but what exactly memory will it be on the embedded platform?

I do not look at PSS because it doesn't make any sense in my case, I look only at RSS.

What conclusions can I draw from this picture? How exactly to evaluate memory consumption by the application? Look at the RSS size of the process?  Or subtract from this size RSS of all mapped system libraries? What is about heap/stack size?

I would be very grateful for any advises, notes, memory consumption optimizations techniques, DOs and DON'Ts for platforms with extremely small amount of RAM (except obvious - keep amount of data and code to the very minimum). 
I also will appreciate an explanation WHY the program with small amount of code and data (and which doesn't allocate much memory) still consumes a lot of RAM in RSS.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I am finding it very difficult to follow this question despite the effort being put in it..

Comment: There is no code to review. The first snippet of code is just for demonstration purposes. The main question is about memory consumption. How to understand the real size of the application and how to reduce a footprint of the application

Comment: If it would be easy to figure out  myself I would not ask ;)

Comment: And I wanted to reveal my efforts to figure the problem out. I'm not just coming to ask "what is the size of my application" or "how to optimize it". I'm giving details, I spent my time to learn these details so it could help other developers (hopefully). But I still have question, that is why I'm asking here

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9887676/694576

Comment: Thanks. I set 'ulimit -s 32' to limit the stack to 32 KB before calling my program. In the mapping I see that stack now is 32KB but the RSS size is not changed - it is still 600KB, So probably the stack size isn't included in RSS but in VSZ.

Answer (score 0):

> ... fit our program into 256 KB of RAM. I don't have this exact platform on hands, so I compile my project under 32 bit x86 Linux..

And what you now see is that the Linux platform tools make reasonable assumptions of your possible need of stack and heap, given that it nows you run on a big machine, and links-in a reasonable set of library functions for your needs. Some you won't need, but it gives them to you "for free".

To fit in 256 Kb on your *target platform*, you must compile for your target platform and link with the target platform's libraries (and CRT) using the target platform's linker.

Those will make different assumptions, use possibly smaller linbrary footprints, make smaller assumptions on stack and heap space, etcetera. For example, create "Hello World" for the target platform and check its needs on that target platform. Or use a realistic simulator of the target platform and libraries (and not to forget, OS, whch partly dictates what the libraries must do).

And if it is then still too  big, you have to re-write or tweak the whole CRT and all libraries....

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is clear that I can make only assumptions about the target platform without playing with it in real. But I want to make assumptions about a footprint. So can I safely assume that my program will consume 28 KB + 4KB (heap) + 12 KB (stack) ?  Add here libc and other system libraries, but I need to evaluate my program in isolation. Is it a real estimation about memory consumption?

Answer (score 0):

the program needs to be compiled/linked with the embedded device in mind.

For best results use a makefile

use the 'rt' library written for the embedded device

use the start.s file, located, via the makefile, where execution begins.

use 'static' in the linker parameters

use the linker parameters to not include any libraries but what is specifically requested.

do not use libraries written for your development machine.  Only use libraries written for the embedded device.

do NOT include stdio.h, etc. unless specifically written for the embedded device

do NOT call printf() inside a signal handler.

if possible, do not call printf() at all.

instead write a small char output function and have it perform the output through the uart.

do not use signals, instead use interrupts

the resulting application will not run on your PC., but, once loaded, will run on the 256k device

do not call sleep(), rather write your own function that uses a device timer peripheral, that sets the timer and puts the device into powerdown mode.

the time interrupt needs to bring the device out of the powerdown mode.

in the makefile, specifically set the size of the stack, heap, etc.

have the link step output a .map file.  study that map file until you understand everything in it.

use a compiler/linker that is specific for the embedded device

you probably will need to include a function that initializes the peripherals on the device, like the clock, the uart, the timer, the watchdog, and any other built in peripherals that the code actually uses.

you will need a file that allocates the interrupt table, and a small function to handle each of the interrupts, even though most of those functions will do nothing beyond clearing the appropriate interrupt pending flag and returning from the interrupt

you will probably need a function to periodically refresh the watchdog, conditionally, depending on an indication that the main function is still cycling regularily.  I.E the main function loop and the initialization function will refresh the watchdog

Comment: Thank you for sharing the best practices to reduce the footprint with me, I do appreciate this. If I understand correctly what you're trying to say to me - there is no fair way to estimate the memory consumption for the small platform when running the code on a big development system? And If I look at my code which takes 28 + 4 + 12 = 44 KB of code I can't assume it will fit into 256 KB of RAM? Because of the system libs? But if to speak only about the program itself - is it a good estimation? System libs is a completely another story - I agree that I have to limit the use of glibc to minimum